# Generating SEF pages in a php/mysql/apache environment

Tags: php, mysql, apache2, sef

I'm planning to create a blog using php/mysql on apache (probably on a linux machine, if this info is at all important). I would like to test out YII framework for that purpose, and would also like to have fun while developing.

Since I used to develop in Joomla in my past, I know the importance of Search Engine Friendly URLs, and I would like to implement it somehow.

Any ideas on what to use with some general (or specific) instructions would be appreciated.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii seems to have [a full-fledged guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url) on how to set up nice URLs.

Comment: :) Thank you... I tend to think ahead... way too ahead :).